# Mapping scope to profileFields

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm using Passport and Passport-Facebook Strategy.
There are two options we can pass:

```
"scope": ["email", "user_about_me", "..."]
```

and

```
profileFields: ["id", "emails", "..."]
```

Is there a map somewhere online where i can find out which profileFields i can access for each scope added?

Example:

```
"scope": ["user_about_me"]
```

I have tried

```
profileFields: ["about_me", "user_about_me"]
```

none of the profileFields work

So here are the possible scopes i can ask permission for:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5